# Detecting newlines in textbox content and creating an array

Tags: php, arrays, textbox, split, newline

I got a mediocre problem with my php script showing me the finger whenever I try to split the contents of a textbox from another page by its newline characters. The reasons could be multiple as I'm not that familiar with php (normally C#).
Maybe I messed up with the newline detection. Mabye that textbox produces something else than "\n" for breaks.

The plan is to detect special characters and if they're not contained, then add something and save to a file. If there are several lines, create an array by splitting at newline, add something to all the parts and save each one of them in a file.

Code for the textbox:

```
<form method='post' action='../inc/convert.php'>
        <p>
            <label for="seq">Enter sequence here:</label>
            <textarea id="seq" class="reset" name="textbox_input" cols="80" rows="5" style="width: 489px; height: 135px;"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
        <input type="submit" name="textbox_text" align="middle" />
        </p>
    </form>
```

Code for the php script:

```
<?php
$textbox_content = $_POST['textbox_input'];
//$post = print_r($_POST, true);
//file_put_contents("../files/meh.txt", $post);

if (strpos($textbox_content,'<') !== false)
{
    echo "unallowed syntax!";
}
else
{
$appearance = substr_count( $textbox_content , '\n');

switch(true) #if sequence doesn't have a multifasta format
{
    case ($appearance == 0):

        if (strpos($textbox_content,'>') !== true) #if just one sequence without fasta format
        {
            $santas = ">Organism.1 Indentifier.1 / 0-0 ";
            $helper = $santas . $textbox_content;
            $file = "../files/file1.mfa";
            file_put_contents($file, $helper);

        }
        else
        {
            $parts = preg_split('/[\n\r]+/', $textbox_content); #if multiple sequences without fasta
            $max = sizeof($parts);
            $runner = 1;
            for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
            {            
                $santas = ">Organism." . (string)$runner . "Indentifier."+(string)$runner . "/ 0-0 ";
                $helper = $santas . $textbox_content;
                $file = "../files/file" . (string)$runner . ".mfa";
                $content = serialize($parts[$i]);
                file_put_contents($file, $content);
                $runner++;        
            }
        }
        break;



    case ($appearance == 1): #if just one sequence with fasta format

        $file = "../files/newjob.mfa";
        file_put_contents($file, $textbox_content);
        break;


    case ($appearance >= 2): #if several sequences with fasta format

        $parts = explode("\n" , $textbox_content); #if multiple sequences without fasta format
        $max = sizeof($parts);
        $runner = 1;
        for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
        {
            $file = "../files/fastafile" . (string)$runner . ".mfa";
            file_put_contents($file, $parts[$i]);
            $runner++;   
        }

        break;
}
```

}
?>

It just creates one file, with the little extra in front and then the whole textbox content instead of several files.

As you can see, I also tried to figure out what the textbox content looks like and it came out like this:

```
Array
(
   [textbox_input] => >abc
   >abc
   >abc
   [textbox_text] => Senden
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = explode("\n", $_POST['textbox_input']);
```

`"\n"` is the new line representation (only works in double quotes!). The explode function searches for occurences of the delimitter (1st param) in the input string (2nd param) and splits on those delimmiters into an array.

That should server your needs.

Comment: Actually, the solution was to replace the "\n" with something else as the explode function didn't detect it. Why ever. I had put it into '' and "" to test before but it didn't work.